# Install Eclipse IDE for java ee dev via apt-get. Is it Possible?

Tags: installation, java, eclipse

I try install `Eclipse` `IDE` for Java EE Developers.

I run in terminal this command:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

This ends successfully.

But when I see it, is installed the Eclipse Classic Version - not for Java EE Developers.

So, This is my question: it is possible install Eclipse IDE for Java EE Dev via `apt-get` command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, but you can update classic version for it to be same as Eclipse for J2EE version.
The best way (which I know) is:
1.In Eclipse go Help -> Install new Software...
2.Press Add...
3.In address enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ and name - whatever you like.
4.Install JavaEE Developer Tools (under "Web, XML, JavaEE, and OSGi Enterprise Tools")
5(Optional, but very useful).Install Marketplace Client (General Purpose Tools -> Marketplace Client).

That's about it, after this you should have the same environment as client you would download from Eclipse.org.

Comment: Step 3 only partly worked for me -- the source packages seem to have an unresolved dependency. And then JavaEE Developer Tools was not an option.  Your answer would be better if it gave ideas of how to troubleshoot the process.

Comment: the link needs to be the one from Guangs answer

Comment: If you feel that the answer needs an edit - please make one.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricWilson I think the problem is that the link refers to Helios edition and you might be using some other edition like Galileo. Eg- For Galileo the link is: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/

Comment: I'm using Indigo. In any case I've settled on the fact that downloading the zip file is the best way to "install" eclipse for Java EE.

Comment: Why is 5) useful, and is that included in what you would have from Eclipse.org? Please edit your answer.

Comment: The solution above does not work. There are no options to install JavaEE Dev Tools even if the link is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse comes with differents configurations but there is always the same "eclipse" as core application. They are the same Eclipse with differents collections of plugins that you can install, remove and update trough the package manager integrated in Eclipse itself.
That's why you can't find the Eclipse you want with an apt package manager.

You also do not need to install eclipse or java ( the .bin version from the Oracle website ), they can be unpacked in a local folder, for example you can unpack this two in your home folder and then add the `-vm` option to the `eclipse.ini` or launch eclipse with the `-vm` option, example:

```
\local\path\to\eclipse -vm \local\path\to\the\java\machine\used_by_eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup Eclipse with Java then install **Java Development Tools (JDT)** package for Eclipse.

`sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt`